# i need to skip a part in my code i dont't know how

Tags: java

i wanna know how can i skip my try again part if my input in 'input' is invalid. for example, I enter 'o' as my choice. it should display "invalid input" and it should display the menu part (skipping the try again). help me please.

```
public class Menu {

    public static void MainMenu() {
        Part1 call1 = new Part1();
        Part2 call2 = new Part2();
        Part3 call3 = new Part3();
        Part4 call4 = new Part4();

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String yn = null;


        do {
            System.out.println("\t\t---HOMEWORK---");
            System.out.println("\tI  for PART 1");
            System.out.println("\tII  for PART 2");
            System.out.println("\tIII  for PART 3");
            System.out.println("\tIV  for PART 4");
            System.out.print("\tEnter input:     ");
            String input = in.next();

            do {
                switch (input) {

                    case "I":
                        call1.one();
                        break;

                    case "II":
                        call2.two();
                        break;

                    case "III":
                        call3.three();
                        break;

                    case "IV":
                        call4.four();
                        break;

                    case "V":
                        System.exit(0);
                        break;

                    default:
                        System.out.println("invalid input");
                        break;

                }

                System.out.print("try again? -Y- || -N-     :  ");
                yn = in.next();

            } while (yn.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));

        } while (yn.equalsIgnoreCase("n"));
    }

}
```

Comment: something like `if(inputWasValid) { ... }`?

Comment: i think what i'm trying to say is if i entered an invalid input, it wont give the user the option to try again. it would show the --HOMEWORK-- part and the user would enter another choice

Comment: @Ms.Smoak Are none of the below question worth accepting?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Menu {

public static void MainMenu() {
    Part1 call1 = new Part1();
    Part2 call2 = new Part2();
    Part3 call3 = new Part3();
    Part4 call4 = new Part4();

    boolean inputWasValid = false; 

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String yn = null;


    do {
        System.out.println("\t\t---HOMEWORK---");
        System.out.println("\tI  for PART 1");
        System.out.println("\tII  for PART 2");
        System.out.println("\tIII  for PART 3");
        System.out.println("\tIV  for PART 4");
        System.out.print("\tEnter input:     ");
        String input = in.next();

        do {
            switch (input) {

                case "I":
                    call1.one();
                    break;

                case "II":
                    call2.two();
                    break;

                case "III":
                    call3.three();
                    break;

                case "IV":
                    call4.four();
                    break;

                case "V":
                    System.exit(0);
                    break;

                default:
                    inputWasValid = true;
                    System.out.println("invalid input");
                    break;

            }
            if (inputWasValid) {
               break;
            }
            System.out.print("try again? -Y- || -N-     :  ");
            yn = in.next();

        } while (yn.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));

    } while (yn.equalsIgnoreCase("n"));
}
```

}

as @Kevin say, you can try this.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you want something like this:

```
    ...
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String yn = null;
    boolean retry;


    do {
        System.out.println("\t\t---HOMEWORK---");
        System.out.println("\tI  for PART 1");
        System.out.println("\tII  for PART 2");
        System.out.println("\tIII  for PART 3");
        System.out.println("\tIV  for PART 4");
        System.out.print("\tEnter input:     ");

        String input = in.next();
        retry = true;

        switch (input) {

            ...

            default:
                System.out.println("invalid input");
                break;
        }

        System.out.print("try again? -Y- || -N-     :  ");
        yn = in.next();

        // might want to do check & loop here to see if user enters just Y or N 

        if(retry && yn.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) retry = false;   

    } while (retry);
```

With this, you get the following results:

- Input `I` try again `Y` will run through loop again
- Input `I` try again `N` will terminate loop
- Input `P` try again `Y` will run through loop again (invalid input displayed, but give user choice of continuing)
- Input `P` try again `N` will terminate loop (invalid input displayed, user decides to not continue)